# What is the argument of $0$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Very easy but bit more thinking is making it complicated. What is the argument of $0$? The number $0$ can be written as $0+0i$ thus its argument is $\tan^{-1}(0/0)$ which is undefined; so, is the argument of $0$ undefined?

Comment: This is the same as asking what is the angle made by *point*. We know that angle is formed between *two rays only*, dont we? So there is no such thing as angle a point makes. Therefore 0 has **no argument**.

Answer (score 1):

The number $0$ may have arbitrary argument, that's why we usually don't define one. For example take the exponential form of complex number (or trigonometric one), then:

$$0=0\cdot e^{i\theta}\quad\text{or}\quad 0=0\cdot(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))$$

Any $\theta$ satisfies these equations.

#### Indeterminate form of type $0/0$

You have already found that we may write $$\arg(0)=\arctan(0/0)$$

Formally it is not true, but we can try to describe it using limits.

$$\arg(x+yi)=\arctan(y/x)$$

Take some path i.e. two sequences tending to $0$:

$$x_n\to0\quad\text{and}\quad y_n\to0$$

Value of $\arg(0)$ is described as

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \arctan\left(\frac{y_n}{x_n}\right)$$

The problem is that for different sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ the limit may give different results. We usually say that the limit

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$

doesn't exist as it's path-dependent.

#### Transformation

Another way of thinking is the following. Take the Jacobian of transformation

$$x=r\cos(\theta),\quad y=r\sin(\theta)$$

It is equal to

$$\frac{\partial(x, y)}{\partial(r,\theta)}=r$$

The transformation is not invertible if the Jacobian is equal to $0$, therefore for $r=0$.

Answer (score 1):

It is, indeed, undefined, since $0=0e^{i\theta}$ for any real $\theta.$ It is the only complex number with an undefined principal argument, though one could argue (pun intended) that it has any real argument we like.

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined. An easy way to see that it would be difficult to define it uniquely is to consider that the argument of a product is the sum of arguments, i.e:

$$\arg(z_{1}z_{2})=\arg(z_{1})+\arg(z_{2})$$

If we consider $z_{1} = 0$, we find:

$$\arg(0)=\arg(0)+\arg(z_{2})$$

So therefore, $\arg(0)$ has an arbitrary value, we cannot uniquely define it.

Comment: I would rather say that $\arg(ab)=\arg(a)+\arg(b)$ doesn't hold for $a=0\lor b=0$ since as you can see it implies that $\arg(z_2)=0$.